# Renaming files in mass in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, concatenation, renaming

When collecting data, I've currently named my files in the following format:

```
1_10.mat
```

Where the number before the underscore is a continent:

```
1- Africa
2- South America
3- Central America
```

The second number is the day in that continent the measurement was made on. What I'd like to do is to add the country the measurements were made in onto the end of the filename as well. For example:

`1_1 --> 1_10` I want to rename each one to `1_1_Zaire --> 1_10_Zaire`

`1_11 --> 1_14`, I want to rename each one to `1_11_Kenya --> 1_11_Kenya`

How could I do this while keeping all the .mat files in the same folder? I'd prefer to use MATLAB for the renaming if possible.

I understand the algorithm will be something like the following:

1. name a directory with all the .mat files
2. make a for loop from bound 1 to bound x
3. concatenate the phrase I want

The only problem is, I don't know how to get the length of the loop, and I don't understand how MATLAB reads files in a directory.

This is what I've tried.

```
directory = 'C:\place';
for 1 : 9
    curName = directory.name;
    s = '_Africa';
    laterName = (strcat(directory,s)).name;
end
```

Comment: You don't say at all what you've already tried. And if you don't understand how Matlab reads files in, try searching their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you started:

```
directory = 'C:\place\';

% Filter the list of files using * as a wildcard.
file = strcat(directory, '*.mat');

% Get a list of files and concatenate them with the directory name.
results = dir(file);

file_name = strcat(directory, '\', num2cell(char(results.name), 2)')';

% The total number of files
nfile = length(file_name)

% Loop through each file.
for i = 1: nfile
    curName = file_name{i}
    d = textscan(curName, '%3s%f%1s%f');
    if (d{2} == 1)
        if (1 <= d{4} && d{4} <= 10)
            laterName = sprintf('.\\%i_%i_Zaire.mat', d{2}, d{4})
        elseif  (11 <= d{4} && d{4} <= 14)
            laterName = sprintf('.\\%i_%i_Kenya.mat', d{2}, d{4})
        end
    else
        % ...
    end
end
```

Comment: One issue that I'm running into is that it's ordering a file like 1_10 directly after 1_1, or 1_20 after 1_2. 

The preferred format is in increasing sequence after the underscore, such as 1_1, 1_2...1_9, 1_10, 1_10....1_19, 1_20, 1_21

Comment: I don't think the order matters.  You can loop out of order, then read the numbers from the old file name and rename appropriately.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, and sorry to pester you, but I've also noticed that the %3s term would actually take the first 3 characters from the full name including the directory, so for example "c:\"

Comment: I don't know Matlab well enough to really answer your question, but personally, I'd use Excel & VBA for this kind of job.  Please see this.
 --
http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/renaming-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/